# UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position

Tags: python, html, css, flask, site

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, render_template, flash, request, g, redirect
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/auth", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def auth():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form.get('login')
        password = request.form['password']
        print(username, password)
    return render_template("auth.html"), "Данные получены"

@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')

@app.route("/profile/<username>")
def profile(username):
    return f"Профиль: {username}"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Вот HTML-Код страницы `auth`:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>DATAPLUS: Авторизация</title>
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Icon.png" type="image/png">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>АВТОРИЗАЦИЯ</h1>
            <div class="divider"></div>
            <button class="into_but" onclick="window.location.href='/'">НА ГЛАВНУЮ</button>
            <a class="ent" href="/"><img src="enter_button.png" alt="ВОЙТИ"></a>
            <form action="/auth" method="POST">
                <input class="log_into" type="text" name="login" placeholder="Введите логин">
                <input class="pas_into" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Введите пароль">
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

При открывании сайта главная страница открывается спокойно но почему то не загружается CSS код. Но не так важно. Главное что при переходе на auth страницу появляется вечная загрузка и выводится огромная ошибка в консоли:

```
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://(АДРЕС)
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 887-399-756
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2023 15:38:43] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2023 15:38:43] "GET /style1.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2023 15:38:47] "GET /auth HTTP/1.1" 0 -
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anato\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 364, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "C:\Users\anato\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 328, in execute
    write(data)
  File "C:\Users\anato\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 265, in write
    self.send_response(code, msg)
  File "C:\Users\anato\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\server.py", line 502, in send_response
    self.send_response_only(code, message)
  File "C:\Users\anato\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\server.py", line 517, in send_response_only
    (self.protocol_version, code, message)).encode(
                                            ^^^^^^^
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 11-16: ordinal not in range(256)
```